# Dictionary Comprehension in python (Generate a dictionary of alphabets where values are one one alphabet ahead of keys)

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to generate

```py
dict1 = {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd', 'd': 'e', 'e': 'f', 'f': 'g', 'g': 'h', 'h': 'i', 'i': 'j', 'j': 'k', 'k': 'l',
         'l': 'm', 'm': 'n', 'n': 'o', 'o': 'p', 'p': 'q', 'q': 'r', 'r': 's', 's': 't', 't': 'u', 'u': 'v', 'v': 'w',
         'w': 'x', 'x': 'y', 'y': 'z', 'z': 'a'}
```

such a dictionary using dictionary comprehension in python?

I am trying

```
dict1 = {chr(a):chr(a+1) for a in range(97,123)}
```

but I dont know how to get 'z':'a' instead of 'z':'{'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modulo 26 to circle back to 'a' after z. A simple example would be

```
dict1 = {chr(a%26+97):chr((a+1)%26+97) for a in range(27)}

#Output
dict1 = {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd', 'd': 'e', 'e': 'f', 'f': 'g', 'g': 'h', 'h': 'i', 'i': 'j', 'j': 'k', 'k': 'l', 'l': 'm', 'm': 'n', 'n': 'o', 'o': 'p', 'p': 'q', 'q': 'r', 'r': 's', 's': 't', 't': 'u', 'u': 'v', 'v': 'w', 'w': 'x', 'x': 'y', 'y': 'z', 'z': 'a'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood